# Slight regex confusion - $ behavior when using multiline flag

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following text:

```
!
interesting1 a
not interesting b
interesting2 c
!
interesting1 a
not interesting b
interesting2 c
!
interesting1 a
not interesting b
interesting2 c
not interesting arbitrary text d
!
```

As you may have guessed, I want to extract `a` and `c` from every section. The `interesting2 c` line is optional, but I only need `a` if there is also `c` (section-wise).

Using `!\n(interesting1 (?P<a>.*?)$.*?(?:interesting2 (?P<c>.*?))?$\n(?=!))` I get:

`a` and `c` from the top 2 sections, but (understandably) `a` and `c\nnot interesting arbitrary text d` from the last section. See on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GCQcvd/1).

I doubt this is the most efficient regex for this situation as this small text requires 438 steps, so I'm open to any other more efficient solutions that will get the correct results.

If I change the regex to `!\n(interesting1 (?P<a>.*?)$.*?(?:interesting2 (?P<c>\w+))?$\n(?=!))` (`\w+` instead of `.*?` in capture group `c`) the only thing it matches in the third section is `a` (as expected since `\w` does not include `\n`).

What I don't understand is how to use `$` in order to specify an optional line of arbitrary text between 
 `interesting2 c` and the closing `!`.

Using different variations of optional non-capturing groups and `$` don't give me the correct results. I even tried optional non-capturing groups in the lookahead part (to signify that we may have additional/optional stuff before the !).

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is there a reason why you have to match the line between `c` and `!`? Why not just end the match after the `c`? 2) Judging from your regex, it seems that the line containing the `c` is optional, but there's no hint of this in your question. Is it correct to assume that the `a` will exist in every section, but the `c` may be missing?

Comment: @Aran-Fey 1. I only care about the values of `a` and `c`. If you are referring to the capture group around the entire section it is only for debugging the current regex.  2. In theory yes, the `c` line is optional but I only need `a` if there is `c` (section-wise). I check later in the code if both capture groups are not empty. Otherwise the `a` and `c` values get mixed. I'll add this information to the question.

Comment: You misunderstood my first question. Basically I'm asking why you have that `(?=!)` lookahead in your regex. If you remove that lookahead and take off the `?` after the `c` capture group, your regex will work correctly: `!\n(interesting1 (?P<a>.*?)$.*?(?:interesting2 (?P<c>.*?))$)`. That's why I was wondering why you were purposely making your regex match the `d` line even though you're not interested in it. But I guess it doesn't really matter anyway.

Comment: @Aran-Fey If I remove the lookahead then the sections are not separated correctly when the `interesting2 c` line is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't understand is how to use `$` in order to specify an optional line of arbitrary text between `interesting2 c` and the closing `!`.

That's because `$` has nothing to do with matching an optional line of text. `$` is just an anchor that asserts a position at the end of the string (or before a newline, if the regex is in multi-line mode). It is not at all required for matching a line of text.

The reason why your regex doesn't work is very simple: It's missing something that would match the optional line. As I've said before, `$` is just an anchor - it doesn't *consume* any text. So in order to successfully match your `(?=!)` lookahead, the group `c` has to grow and match all the text up to the `!` character. To prevent this from happening, you have to add something that can match the last line, like a `.*?` or `[^\n]*`.

In this specific case, though, it's not as simple as adding `.*?` before the `(?=!)` lookahead. Why? Because the `c` group is optional, and adding a `.*?` at the end would prevent the `c` group from matching:

```
!\n(interesting1 (?P<a>.*?)$.*?(?:interesting2 (?P<c>\w+))?$\n.*?(?=!))
                            ^  ^                              ^
                            |  |                              this .*? would grow
                            |  |                              and consume the
                            |  |                              "interesting2 c"
                            |  this group is optional, so it would be skipped
                            this .*? would match the empty string
```

So it's probably best to rewrite the regex from scratch.

Here's how I would write it:

```
!\ninteresting1 (?P<a>.*)(?:\n[^!].*)*\ninteresting2 (?P<c>.*)
```

The logic is pretty straightforward:

1. `!\ninteresting1 (?P<a>.*)` matches the first line and captures `a`
2. `(?:\n[^!].*)*` skips any line that doesn't start with a `!`
3. `\ninteresting2 (?P<c>.*)` matches and captures `c`

This is slightly different from your regex, in that it will only produce a match if both `a` and `c` exist within a section. See also the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT12Of/1).

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
import re

text=\
"""
!
interesting1 a
not interesting b
interesting2 c
!
interesting1 a
not interesting b
interesting2 c
!
interesting1 a
not interesting b
interesting2 c
not interesting d
!
"""

pa = re.compile(r'^interesting[12] ([a-zA-Z]){1}', re.MULTILINE)
m = pa.findall(text)
print(m)
```

It has 6 mathces, 128 steps.

[image]